# Multiple while statements - How to

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a problem with my script.

I have this:

```
<?php
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE id!='".$userdata['membership']."'");

while($md = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)):
  echo '<td class="header">'.$md['name'].'</td>';
endwhile;
?>
```

That works. But if further down the page, I add this:

```
<?php
while($md = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)):
  echo '<td class="result">'.$md['number_of_ads'].'</td>';
endwhile;
?>
```

It doesn't output anything. Why?

Comment: It looks like you've already iterated through the while the first time, so you're never making it into the second one.  You need to reset `mysql_fetch_assoc($r)` so that you enter the second loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe because there's no more elements to fetch. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want to fetch the data back from the beginning, you need to add this before the second block of code:

```
mysql_data_seek($r, 0);
```

That will reset the internal pointer to the beginning.

Comment: +1 Dayum son. Got to it before myself. The main point here is using `mysql_data_seek()`; the OP isn't getting any new results because he's reached the end of the resultset.

Comment: That did it! Is it save to continue to reset the data multiply times on a page? (I need some while loops)

Comment: Yes it's safe. If you need to loop through the data several times, then you should reset it every time before the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure if you've noticed, but when you find an answer useful, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the "tick" icon below the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have fetched all the rows from `$r`, successive call to it will not return any row.

So when the first while loop ends, there is nothing to fetch from the query result in the second loop

Answer (score 1):

The fetch_association function draws rows from a resultset. The first while loops over the result set. If you want to loop that data twice you need to reset the data.